# Google Analytics post request not appearing

Tags: python, google-analytics, python-requests

I'm sending an `event` request to Google Analytics server-side using a POST request to `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect` from Python/Flask (via the `requests` library). I'm testing it by looking at the real-time events page.

- If I try my request on the GA Hit Builder, it works perfectly.
- If I paste the request directly into my browser with the URL parameters, it works perfectly.
- If I post from my app, I get a status 200, suggesting it has worked, but nothing appears in the live events view.
- If I post from my app to `/debug/collect` I get this response, which looks OK to me, but nothing in the live events view:

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-18542058-16\u0026cid=ax5b51b5beaa4f0\u0026t=event\u0026ec=Tasks\u0026ea=View task\u0026el=25\u0026ev=0"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

The request is: `https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect
v=1&tid=UA-18542058-16&cid=ax5b51b5beaa4f0&t=event&ec=Tasks&ea=View+task&el=25&ev=0`.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify `dl` (document location URL) parameter in the hit or both `dh` (document host name) and `dp` (document path) parameters:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=it#dl

Alternative **disable** any filter in the view and **the tick to exclude bots**.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried that, but it doesn't seem to have helped. :(

Comment: Check in the event report, not the one in real time but the actual one. Real time is not reliable.

Comment: The only events that appear in the report are those I send via the working methods above, but none directly from my app.

Comment: Do you have any filter in the view? Or the tick to exclude bots?

Comment: Thank you @Michele. Unchecking that filter worked, but why is GA treating my app (either remote or from localhost) as a bot?

Comment: Great! I edited my answer adding my suggest. Anyway, the tick to 'exclude bots' will ensure that all bots on the Interactive Advertising Bureau’s International Spiders & Bots List are excluded from your Google Analytics data. The algorithm has been modified by Google and is actually more restrictive. It probably uses several conditions, i.e. service provider. For example, it may not be the case but it could be one of the conditions, in your hit there is no screen resolution, no source/medium, ... so it could be interpreted as a fictitious call even if it contains the min of parameters required

Comment: That might make sense, since it's being sent server side it's not containing browser data etc. I'll have a go at sending that alongside